# Unity Hanging On Application Reload

Tags: unity

I have recently added Vivox general voice chat to the game I am working on. Ever since adding it, I have run into issues with the application reload time after editing a script. If I edit a script and switch back to Unity, it hangs on the application reload window for a very long time, most times never recovering until I force close Unity or until Unity just crashes. Has anyone run into a similar issue with this or any other package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are ending your sessions with Vivox and logging out when the editor quits. You can use the `void OnApplicaitonQuit()` function in Unity and add code there to end the session and log the user out. If you don't close the sessions and logout it will build up in the garbage collector and cause Unity to freeze up.